# filling a list with X [] (empty lists)

Tags: prolog

```
fillwith(X,List2):-
    length(List2,Y)
    ,Y>=X;
    append(List2,[[]],List3)
    ,fillwith(X,List3).
```

the problem here is that once it reach the target it starts it do something weird,it goes back to the first call it made.
for example:

```
fillwith(3,List2):-
    length(List2,Y)
    ,Y>=X;
    append(List2,[[]],List3)
    ,fillwith(X,List3).
```

here in the first call List2 = [[]],in the second call list2 = [[],[]],in the third call list2 = [[],[],[]].
however when it reach that it start to (i guess back-track) and i end up with the first call only.

Comment: Please give a concrete example, when your program should be true. It is unclear to me what the `X` is about. Should `fillwith(X,[[],[]])` succeed? Pretend you have written the program already: show examples how you would use it.

Comment: The X is the number of empty lists to be appended to the list,
as i expressed earlier when X is 2 the pred should succeed if List is equal to [[],[]] and if 4 should be [[],[],[],[]].

Answer (score 1):

```
fillwith(X,List2):- 
   must_be(nonneg, X),
   length(List2, X),
   maplist(=([]), List2).
```

If you would like *append* use:

```
fillwith(X, List2), append(List1, List2, List3).
```

Answer (score 1):

I am still not sure, what you want, but from the comments, you simply want:

```
fillwith(X, Nils) :-
   length(Nils, X),
   nils(Nils).

nils([]).
nils([[]|Nils]) :-
   nils(Nils).
```

The goal `nils(Nils)` could be equally expressed as `maplist(=([]),Nils)`.

```
?- fillwith(4, Xs).
   Xs = [[],[],[],[]].
?- fillwith(X, Xs).
   X = 0, Xs = []
;  X = 1, Xs = [[]]
;  X = 2, Xs = [[],[]]
;  X = 3, Xs = [[],[],[]]
;  X = 4, Xs = [[],[],[],[]]
;  ... .
```